# How to implement JSR-303 for Enums

Tags: java, enums, bean-validation

I'm building a Rest WS and to validate the request elements I'm using a JSR-303 BeanValidation, but there's a field type Enum.

EmploymentType.java

```
public enum EmploymentType {
    EMPTY, FULL, PARTTIME, CONTRACT, CASUAL;

    public static EmploymentType getDefaultEnum() {
        return EMPTY;
    }
}
```

and the class I'm using use to implement this:

Employment.java

```
public class Employment implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull(message="employmentType does not accept null values")
    private EmploymentType employmentType;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="orgData does not accept null values")
    private OrgData orgData;

    public Employment() {
        employmentType = EmploymentType.getDefaultEnum();
        orgData = new OrgData();
    }

    public EmploymentType getEmploymentType() {
        return employmentType;
    }

    public void setEmploymentType(EmploymentType employmentType) {
        this.employmentType = employmentType;
    }

    public OrgData getOrgData() {
        return orgData;
    }

    public void setOrgData(OrgData orgData) {
        this.orgData = orgData;
    }
}
```

the implementation I developed only prevents the enum being a null object, is there a way to validate that the value of the enum is only within the range of declared values? (EMPTY, FULL, PARTTIME, CONTRACT, CASUAL)

Comment: What else could it be?  If something manages to generate a _valid_ instance of the class (with a non-null `employmentType`), then it must have one of those values.  That's how `enum`s work...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do the validation of the valueOf OR the name of the enum
Here is the excerpt what will make the validation happen

```
public class Employment implements Serializable {

@NotNull(message = "employmentType does not accept null values")
@Valid
private EmploymentType employmentType;

public EmploymentType getEmploymentType() {
    getEmploymentTypeOfEnum();
    return employmentType;
} 

@Pattern(regexp = "EMPTY|FULL")
private String getEmploymentTypeOfEnum(){ // you don't need it to be public
     return employmentType.name();
}
}
```